# Where is color information stored in android apps ?

Tags: applications, root-access, customization, color, development

This might not be the correct place to post this, so please tell me if it isn't. As the title says, I'm trying to find the color palette for android apps while they're installed. I can't decompile the apps, but I can access the apk file. Is there a universal standard file or at least a string of text in a file that I can search for ?

Comment: This information is usually stored (in source) in the appropriate themes.xml files. These files are then packed into the resources of an app. The only way to get the theme information (color, parents, gradients, shapes etc.) is by decompiling said app. Some apps even change their colors at runtime, again requiring you to decompile them.

Answer (score 1):

Under 
values > color.xml

Your themes file ( values > styles.xml ) can link specific colors from this file like follows..

Style Script ..

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

color script ....

```
 <resources>
 <color name="primary_dark">#F28000</color>
 <color name="primary">#FF8700</color>
 <color name="accent">#FF8700</color>
```

Notice that color can link to itself

```
<color name="accent_text">@color/accent</color>
```